# Do I need a transit visa to collect my luggage and check -in my next flight at Frankfurt International Airport?

Tags: visas, transit

I am from Oman, travelling from Vancouver, Canada, to Frankfurt. My final destination is Casablanca, Morocco. I have booked a separate ticket for the final destination. I need to collect my luggage in Frankfurt and check-in my next flight. Flight is after 9 hours from arrival in Frankfurt. I have a valid visa for Canada and my Schengen visa expired in April 2019.

Comment: If both airlines are in the same alliance (but sometime also if they are not), they can send baggages to final destination (also in case of two different tickets). Ask the first airline.

Comment: Unless you can arrange for the luggage to be checked through, you will need a visa.